# Django tasks with deadline date

Tags: python, django

So i got the model Task with a date it should be finished

```py
class Task(models.Model):
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
.....
```

how can i compare the date in template that if deadline date is earlier than today then do something?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in your model:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    def is_end_date(self):
        return datetime.now() > self.end_date
```

and in your template you can use:

```
{% if task.is_end_date %}
    #add your code
{% elif %}
    #add your code
{% endif %}
```